# jQuery scrolls to wrong offset after dynamically loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason this code, which usually scrolls up/down to the start of the specified targetDiv, instead scrolls the page further down the page than the end of where the targetDiv already is.

```
function postData(data, url, divAction, targetDiv) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (divAction == 'hide') {
                $(targetDiv).hide();
                $(targetDiv).empty();
            }
            if (divAction == 'refresh') {
                $(targetDiv).html(response);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: '+=' + $(targetDiv).offset().top + 'px'
                }, 'fast');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error! Plese try again.');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this instead:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(targetDiv).offset().top
}, 'fast');
```

Comment: Thanks! That simple eh.. it probably looks like I was lazy but I really did try to solve this one, I really suck at js!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osmanraif/PdUk3/3/) and it works.
`

```
targetDiv = $('#id1');
$(targetDiv).html("<iframe src=\"www.google.com\" />");
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=' + $(targetDiv).offset().top + 'px'
```

}, 'fast')`